# Losing internet connection just after calling createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am testing the authentication code I implemented using Firebase during loss of internet connectivity.

This is the code where I attempt to sign up user using email and password:

```
if (isConnected()) {
        FirebaseAuthentication.registerUser(email, password);
} else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Network ERROR");
}
```

This is the code for registerUser method:

```
public static void registerUser(String email, String password) {

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
    password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success. Do things

            } else {
                // If sign in fails
                Log.d("AuthEngineDebugger", "Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

While testing, occasionally I find myself in a situation where the connection is lost just after FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(..) is called ... so what I get is that there is a user created in the authentication list in Firebase console ... but the Log line is displayed in logcat (task is unsuccessful). And when I try to get the current user I get null !! ... and when I retry registering when connection is restored ... I get that the email address already exists ... so how to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a work around and gladly it worked ! ...

The problem is when connection is lost, the authentication process is stuck at adding a new user to Firebase console but with no reference to it to manipulate in the code. On other words, getCurrentUser() returns null.

The solution: when the connection is restored and before trying to re-register the user again, sign in the user using the credentials that was used in registering and voila !! now you have your reference back ... now you can delete the user and start the whole registering process all over again or you can continue from where the connection was lost.